# Unicode character is not displaying correctly in my HTML

Tags: html, unicode

I want to put an email address on a website, and protect it (at least a little, I don't want to use JavaScript encoding) from spam.
The method I use is printing Unicode characters in my HTML, so bots don't recognise the email addresses.

The code:

```
<a href="mailto:something&#x40hotmail&#x002Ecom">somethingk&#x40hotmail&#x002Ecom</a>
```

Output:

```
something@hotmailˬom
```

What goes wrong: The dot (002E) displays as a 02EC Unicode character. When I print &#x002E without any text directly next to it, the dot is displayed like it should.

Comment: All characters are Unicode. I suppose you mean **HTML entities**.

Comment: Probably, I have never heard of that name. I'm still experimenting with  this; I haven't yet read a lot about it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Modern bots are smart enough to decode HTML entities. The only way to really prevent a bot from grabbing an email from an HTML page is to not put the email on the page at all.  If you want users to contact you through your website, set up a webform instead that the users can fill out and submit to the server and let the server email you on the user's behalf.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is just for preventing the old bots, a form is not an option here (otherwise I'd have made one). I'll soon make a javascript-encoded email address: there are not many bots with JS capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a semicolon after HTML entities.

```
<a href="mailto:something&#x40;hotmail&#x002E;com">somethingk&#x40;hotmail&#x002E;com</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EmvBc/1/

Comment: Super! That's what I missed :) Thanks (I'll mark as answer when I can)